# I don't know why "console.log(text+"11111")" is output only three times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(This article was written with Google Translate.)

```
import {useState} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [text,setText] = useState('Hi ')

  const updateText=()=>{
    setText('Hello ')
    console.log(text+"22222")
  }
  console.log(text+"11111")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span id="text">{text}</span>
      <button onClick={updateText}>Update</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

The first time "console.log(text+"11111")" is output.
And when I click Update, "console.log(text+"22222")" is output and "console.log(text+"11111")" is output.  Pressing Update once more does the same thing.

However, from then on, even if I click Update, "console.log(text+"11111")" is not output.
I don't know why "console.log(text+"11111")" is output only 3 times.

Comment: `text` doesn't change from `'Hello '`, so your component is not re-rendered

Comment: It may be a browser feature, try it in a different browser. But I think it is all right.

Comment: @DmitriySidyakin - No, nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more words. I think your code works.

Answer (score 0):

When the component is first mounted and your component function is called for the first time, you see `Hi 11111` because the value of `text` is from the initial value you provided in `useState("Hi ")`.

When you click the button, it does `setText('Hello ')`, which **queues** a state update (the update does not happen right away). Since the version of `updateText` that was called closed over the first `text`, you see `Hi 22222`.

When React processes the state update, it sees that `"Hello "` is a different value from `"Hi "`, so it updates the state and calls your component function to re-render. In the re-render, `text` is `"Hello "` and so you see `Hello 11111`.

At that point, clicking the button does `setText('Hello ')`, which queues a state update, and shows `Hello 22222` (because this new version of `updateText` closes over the updated `text`). When the state update is processed, React sees that the state hasn't changed (`"Hello "` is still `"Hello "`), so it doesn't call your component function to re-render, since nothing has changed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Thanks to you, I understand to some extent. However, I wonder why "Hello 11111" is printed once more even though the text has already been changed to Hello.

Comment: @user19121859 - The third paragraph above explains that (or tries to)...?